# Method Overloading is possible in objective c, am i right?

Tags: objective-c

I read everywhere that objective c doesn't support method overloading but i came across different results.
What i know about Method Overloading is "Methods having same name but different parameters".

Please try this:

Interface file

```
-(void)methodoverloading;
-(void)methodoverloading :(int)parameter;
```

Implementation file

```
-(void)methodoverloading{
    NSLog(@"methodoverloading  method with no Parameter");
}
-(void)methodoverloading :(int)parameter{
    NSLog(@"methodoverloading method with Parameter");
}
```

Calling:

```
 [self methodoverloading];
 [self methodoverloading: 100];
```

Result:Ok

2014-06-21 17:16:09.272 BasicFundamentals[869:a0b] methodoveroading  method with no Parameter
2014-06-21 17:16:09.272 BasicFundamentals[869:a0b] methodoveroading method with Parameter

am i right or getting wrong somewhere? Thank You

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Objective C, the signature of a method includes the parameters.

Your two methods:

```
- (void)methodoverloading
```

and

```
- (void)methodoverloading:(int)
```

have different signatures (`methodoverloading` vs. `methodoverloading:`), and thus are different methods.

What people mean when they say that Objective C doesn't support overloading is that you can't define:

```
- (void)method:(int)arg
```

and

```
- (void)method:(NSString *)arg
```

and have the compiler choose between them based on the type you provide.

Comment: Yes, the actual internal names of your first two methods are `methodoverloading` and `methodoverloading:`.  If you have two parms the name would be `methodoverloading:anotherparm:`.  As you indicate, though, the parm type is not a part of the internal name.

Comment: Thank You Mr sapi. This is the answer.i was searching for.